# Can't run search service: Error executing service instance (on)provisioning job

Tags: search, enterprise-search

Yesterday I had to delete search service, I did it simply from CA - click delete search service with associated content. After that come my problem, two databases didn't removed, and search services didn't stop, I stopped service and removed databases by PowerShell but now I'm not able to run new search service I get error in CA and in ULS log I see many:

> Fetching app info failed:
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchServiceNotFoundException:
>   The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service.

In evet log:

> Event 6398 The Execute method of job definition
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceInstanceJobDefinition (ID
>   755f7b69-7c8c-4e2c-bf8d-da10c42f80b1) threw an exception. More
>   information is included below.

Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

> Event 3899 Error executing service instance (un)provisioning job. 
>   Service instance: "SharePoint Server Search" (id
>   "96a3525b-c4e8-41df-bdbe-728b1657553a) "Attempted to perform an
>   unauthorized operation.""

Event 7034

> The Execute method of job definition
>   Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Preservation.PreservationJobDefinition
>   (ID b54f9c39-0798-4a5e-ac8c-6eb72b45e130) threw an exception. More
>   information is included below.

The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service.

Comment: There error reads like your account does not have enough permissions on the sql server. That would explain why you could not remove the old databases and create the new ones. Can you try to create the Search Service Application with PowerShell like with my script: http://melcher.it/2012/07/sharepoint-2013-create-a-search-service-application-and-topology-with-powershell/

Comment: But before I created search service on the same account and so on, I deleted old databases by powershell but now I'm not able to run instance of search, I'm not sure but it seems to me that some of search component wasn't delete and that's wy I can't do this? When I try to create new search service by CA the name of search service is with 1 it looks like this service is always run?

Comment: Have you tried to reboot the SharePoint servers?

Comment: Yes, restart iis, server etc But nothing change, I'm thinking about restore search service from backup, but I'm not sure if it's ok with my case - probably search service corrupted?

Comment: Yepp sounds like something is totally broken. Maybe psconfig fixes that one, its worth a try.

Comment: Maybe I will restore search service from backup? It should restore earlier configuration?

Comment: It could work but I doubt it. I would start with psconfig in the hope that it repairs the services...

Comment: Yes, the Search Service restore failed also, this evening I will try to PSConfigif it also field I will try to restore whole farm, Farm restore, should help?

Comment: How did it go with psconfig?

Comment: I have run SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard because after psconfig.exe -cmd setup /repair nothig changed, next I decided to run farm restore and now there is total disaster, during farm restoring CA and farm stoped and I not able to run it ... I will restore virtual machines from snapshot and I have to recreate farm to run search service because I don't see other way?

Comment: Wow - that sounds bad. Good luck with the restore, hopefully eat your whole weekend!

Comment: By any chance are the iis apppools stopped? Maybe old password or locked account? There should be sth in the eventlog...

Comment: It turned out that wasn't so bad, the farm CA for about 30 minutes has started, there was a problem with content databases, they didn't restore. Search was restored (service application, components) but also without databases but it was. Yesterday I restored virtual machines from snapshot because I was afraid of some hide errors which can happens in the weekend but next week I will try once more but know I try to recreate farm and and then restore only content ...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use eDiscovery, you can safely disable the "eDiscovery In-Place Hold Processing" Timer Job in Central Administration.

Navigate to `Central Admin > Monitoring > Review job definitions` and find the eDiscovery In-Place Hold Processing. Open it and disable it and the Event 6398 stops throwing errors at you.

[image]

Source: [SharePoint event log- "The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Preservation.PreservationJobDefinition (ID) threw an exception."](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/45022ba2-3947-46ac-a9e2-062b184435ed/sharepoint-event-log-the-execute-method-of-job-definition?forum=sharepointgeneral)

> Looks like it was from one of the timer jobs used for ediscovery. I think it's the eDiscovery In-Place Hold Processing timer job which runs hourly to start or remove site level holds. If your users doesn't utilize ediscovery, you can just disable this timer job scheduled run.